# How to configure a "key" relationship in a one-to-many relationship using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I am having issues with configuring a primary or key relationship (one-to-one) from a one-to-many relationship. The scenario is a Company can have multiple addresses, but only one primary address. We opted to track the primary address on the Company using the column PrimaryAddressId.

The Company entity is configured as such in the ModelBuilder

```
internal class CompanyConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CompanyEntity>
{
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CompanyEntity> builder)
        {
            builder
                .HasKey(c => c.Id);

            builder
                .HasMany(c => c.Addresses)
                .WithOne(a => a.Company)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.CompanyId);

            builder
                .HasOne(c => c.Address)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<CompanyEntity>(c => c.PrimaryAddressId);
        }
}
```

The error that I receive when running the project is

```
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'CompanyAddressEntity.Company' of type 'CompanyEntity'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

Comment: You should check this doc.
[One to many relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many). If this doesn't help I try to give you an example.

Answer (score 0):

Address entity shouldn't have the CompanyId.
Rather you should make an address as an independent entity without any parent entity.

Then you should create a join table many to many from Company to Address.

And then add a FK in Company Table to point to the main address

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get ; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryAddressId { get ; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public List<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

}


public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CompanyEntity> builder)
        {
            builder
                .HasKey(c => c.Id);

            builder
                .HasMany(c => c.Addresses)
                .WithMany(a => a.Companies);
                

            builder
                .HasOne(c => c.Address)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.PrimaryAddressId);
        }
}
```

Theoretically, many companies can reside at the same address, and it is the company that depends on address, rather than an address is dependent of a company.

Comment: Believe me this will save you lots of time further in the line, for example when you want to add Employees address or Customer address in future, you can just reuse the same table Address that you created here, and the Customer or the Employee can have AddressId as one of their column as a dependent of Address table